# How to remove padding between chart and legend in Fusion charts ( DonutChart )?

Tags: javascript, fusioncharts

[Extra padding on the right and left of the chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ya1Dv.png)I am placing legend to the right of my DonutChart, but chart is taking unnecessary padding and the legend is too far from the chart

Comment: I just want to place DonutChart in a bootstrap card with legend on the right and disable labels and data values

Comment: Here is a sample for reference - https://codepen.io/ayanbhaduryfc/pen/KKwxmoX

You can control the size of the doughnut using pieRadius attribute at the chart level,

if you still face the problem share a codepen demo to debug

Answer (score 0):

By default, for doughnut charts, the chart automatically calculates the best fit pie radius based on the data provided. However, you can choose to explicitly set the outer radius of the pie chart. Specify the outer radius of the pie/doughnut chart using pieRadius attribute

```
    {
  "chart": {
    "pieRadius": "130",
    "doughnutRadius": "120"
  }
}
```

To know more about this feature please refer - https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-guide/standard-charts/pie-and-doughnut-charts#customize-pie-radius

Here is a demo fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/ueg7ohzq/

Hope this would help.